# Difference with the use of 'ever"

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between:

This is one of the most important concepts you'll ever know.
     and
This is one of the most important concepts you'll know.

Best wishes, 
Boguslaw

Comment: The primary difference is no one would utter the latter.

Answer (score 0):

> This is one of the most important concepts you'll ever know.

This refers to something that will be 'most important' until the end of your life (and beyond if you believe in that sort of thing).

> This is one of the most important concepts you'll know.

Usually no-one would say it like this (as Dan Bron points out). However it could be used as a clause, e.g.

*This is one of the most important concepts you'll know in the next ten minutes but completely forget when the drug wears off.*  [The knowing will come to an end]

or

*This is one of the most important concepts you'll know during your school years but it will be irrelevant after that.*  [The importance will come to an end]

The above contexts are artificial and so is the phraseology but they show that either the knowledge or its importance is temporary if you exclude the word 'ever'.